# Is there a way to redirect from cloudfront to apigateway using data in headers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

We're setting up API on aws apigateway. Idea is that url is in format "example.com/apiName/path" and stage (version) is in html headers. How can I redirect user to specific API and stage using Route53 and/or CloudFront based on our url format

As event for triggering lambda we tried all 4 (viewer request/response, origin request/response). Every time response is 502 or 503. We tried with default lambda hello world code and also tried with only returning {'status':200} but response is the same (503)

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print('In lambda')
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

There is no logs in CloudWatch neither in monitoring graphs in lambda so i assume that code in lambda was never executed

Comment: Checkout Lambda@Edge.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning. It is  Lambda@Edge deployed on CloudFormation distribution.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason only javascript code works for me in Lambda@Edge although Python is supported from August 2019

Answer (score 0):

I actually have been working on the same thing this week, so far this is what i have (sorry its in node.js but you can probably convert it)

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  const response = {
      status: '301',
      statusDescription: 'Found',
      headers: {
          location: [{
              key: 'Location',
              value: "{URL_TO_REDIRECT_TO}",
          }],
      },
  };
  return response
}
```

it will return a 301 redirect to whatever url you specify, which can be your api gateway

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For some reason when using python I get error even if I use code from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html so I decided to do it in js