# How to redirect to POST/GET api gateway requests from lambda@edge?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I am trying to redirect from

`x.foo.com/login`

to

`https://pgasdfddfs6.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/login`

So far I have this code on my lambda@edge (where uri is the path in the domain, example: /login):

```
            response = {
                status: '301',
                headers: {
                    'location': [{ 
                        key: 'Location', 
                        value: 'https://pgasdfddfs6.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev' + uri 
                    }]
                }
            };
```

I found this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58752953/is-there-a-way-to-redirect-from-cloudfront-to-apigateway-using-data-in-headers)

I can make requests to api gateway enpoint declared as GET, but those with POST returns me: `"message": "Missing Authentication Token"`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is `uri`?

Comment: uri is the path in the domain, for example: '/login'

Comment: how is your api is designed, does it require any authentication when you make [POST] request to it.

Comment: No, POST endpoints does not require authentication. I just find out that this is the normal behaviour of redirection, because all the request are made by GET